# How to count the proportion of points in protected areas shape file using R packages?

Tags: r, gps, sf, count

I have some GPS relocation data and I want to calculate the proportion of those points that fall within protected areas. I'm downloading the protected areas using the `wdpar` package which uses `sf` to deal with spatial data.

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323698/counting-points-in-polygons-with-sf-package-of-r) on counting points in polygons was helpful but I haven't been able to integrate the two packages. Hope you can help.

```
# load packages
library(wdpar)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(sf)

# download protected area data 
# (excluding areas represented as point localities)
sa_raw_pa_data <- wdpa_fetch(c("South Africa"))
sa_raw_pa_data 

# reproject data
sa_pa_data <- st_transform(sa_raw_pa_data, 4326)

# plot it
plot(sa_pa_data)

# create some random data
set.seed(123); d = data.frame(long=runif(100,-180,180), lat=runif(100,-90,90))

# here's where I fall down 

# calculate the overlap with something like
    over(d,sa_pa_data$WDPAID)

# or
lengths(st_intersects(sa_pa_data$WDPAID, d))
```

Comment: Try `spatialEco::point.in.poly` as it supports sp and sf class objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to solve it using `st_intersects`:

```
library (sf)

pts <- st_as_sf (d, coords = c ("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)
res <- st_intersects (pts, sa_pa_data)

length (unlist (res)) / nrow (pts) # fraction of intersecting points
```